# Rename specific level of sub folders

Tags: bash, files, rename

I have list of sub folders inside a parent folder as follow:

```
Parent folder
    folder1
       foldera
    folder2
       folderb
    folder3
       folderc
```

I want to rename the subfolders only in the second level by removing the last two charcters in the subfolder name how can I do this? I tried something like

```
find . -depth -type d -exec sh -c 'mv "${0}" "${0%??}"' {} \;
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for `find`, it works with pure `bash`, considering the following directory structure:

```
./folder3
./folder3/folderc
./folder2
./folder2/folderb
./folder1
./folder1/foldera
```

The command:

```
for f in folder*/*/; do mv -v "$f" "${f%???}"; done
```

After:

```
./folder3
./folder3/folde
./folder2
./folder2/folde
./folder1
./folder1/folde
```

The [filename expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) matches here only folders within the subfolder; `folder*/*/`, that's why there is a slash at the end. The `mv` command remove the last two characters, in the case above it's 3 characters because the ending slash also counts in the variable value.

Comment: Thanks! Kindly why you used echo before mv?

Comment: @MJA Thats a mistake, sry. I echoed the command before I tested it and I copied the wrong one, I correted it.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use the mindepth and maxdepth argument
Here is the command that I used:

```
`find folder -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec sh -c 'mv "${0}" "${0%?}"' {} \;`
```

Also note that I used ${0$?} instead of the double ?? that you used. One way to debug find problems like these is to apend your action with echo. So in the above example you would place an echo before the mv command.

```
$ find .
.
./folder
./folder/folder1
./folder/folder1/foldera
./folder/folder2
./folder/folder2/folderb
./folder/folder3
./folder/folder3/folderc
$ find folder -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec sh -c 'mv "${0}" "${0%?}"' {} \;
$ find .
.
./folder
./folder/folder1
./folder/folder1/folder
./folder/folder2
./folder/folder2/folder
./folder/folder3
./folder/folder3/folder
```

Incidentally, I could have used `find .` or `find folder` since I was in the parent directory of folder. However, if you use `find .` for your exec command, then every subdirectory in the parent directory would have been converted. It is usually better to explicitly list out the directory when you are doing moves, deletes, etc to avoid unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks! Kindly one more question. how can this command find sub folders of different names not only the ones named "folder". ?

Comment: The command finds any directory at the specified level regardless of the name. When I specified "find folder ..." that was just the starting directory.